# How to create a table with django models inside the app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
my_api
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── heroes
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── serializers.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── views.py
```

I am trying to build a simple rest api with drf.
created a directory heroes inside the `my_api` and created a new class.
now `my_api/heroes/models.py` looks like this:

```
class Hero(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    power = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    my_fav = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The problem is, whenever I try to migrate this table doesn't get created. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Did you include the app in your settings.py?

Comment: yeap, i always do that in a first place

Comment: You can also try `python manage.py makemigrations <my app>` to force migrations for that app

Comment: i tried `python3 manage.py makemigrations my_api` - nothing. then `python3 manage.py makemigrations my_api.heroes` - nothing again. then `python3 manage.py makemigrations heroes` and it did the thing I wanted(despite `heroes` is not an app)!!! maybe it will be useful for others. Thanks daniel for the help

Comment: Your structure is all wrong - if `my_api` is an `app` then your `heroes` directory should be on the same level as `my_api`. If `my_api` is a `project` then you should move your `models.py`, `admin.py` etc. files to their own `app` within your `my_api` project.

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

Looks like you messed up the folder structure.
From what I see you have one app "heroes" inside another app "my_api".

How did you created the structure?.

Comment: I'm trying to try everything out and understand django better

Comment: understand but this is not a "standard" forlder/app structure for Django so most likely it's the reason it fails